# UITableView in Swift: Offscreen cells are not pre-loaded

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift

I have a little problem with UITableView. Cells that are offscreen are not loaded when I first scroll down. When I scroll up (so that the not showing cells are offscreen again) and scroll down again they suddenly show up. I think this has something to do with `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. Any idea how to fix this?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCellClass
return cell
```

Comment: Show more of your code. You need to setup your cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Not only "dequeue" it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the intended behaviour of a `UITableView`. The whole point of a `UITableView` is to queue up cells that are needed and release cells that aren't needed to manage memory.

If you would like the cells to be all loaded (I would recommend against this, horrible performance and memory usage), populate a scroll view with views offsetted by some y constant for every row.

Once again, cells aren't loaded for a reason and that's the whole point for a `UITableView`. Apple didn't do a load-all implementation and neither do I think you should.

Comment: Thanks, but why do the offscreen cells not show up immediately when scrolling down?

Comment: @Jack_55 likely you missed some proper implementation. Update your question with some code :-)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Seems like I had checked the hidden option for the cells causing this behavior. When removed it works flawlessly.