# Extremely weird behavior with table cells when going off screen

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Here is the really weird behavior. When the table view is first loaded, it looks like this:

[image]

Now, when I scroll down and then scroll back up, the buttons appear on cells that didn't have buttons on them before! Like so:

[image]

I know this has to do with "This is the intended behaviour of a UITableView. The whole point of a UITableView is to queue up cells that are needed and release cells that aren't needed to manage memory" as described in this post: [UITableView in Swift: Offscreen cells are not pre-loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30152529/uitableview-in-swift-offscreen-cells-are-not-pre-loaded).

Here is my code:

```
var messages = [String]()

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CathyTaskLogTableViewCell

    if messages[indexPath.row] != "" {
        cell.messageButton.hidden = false
    }

    return cell
}
```

Anybody have a solution to this problem?

Comment: try by adding else part to if condition 'else { cell.messageButton.hidden = true}'

Comment: @iDhaval-Please add your code in the answer so that other people can get the answer.I Think it is accepted by Jae

Answer (score 1):

The reason for getting this result is because of `UITableViewCell` is being reuse.

```
if messages[indexPath.row] != "" {
    cell.messageButton.hidden = false
}
else
{
    cell.messageButton.hidden = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions to your problem:

1. Always set the `hidden` property:

   ```
   cell.messageButton.hidden = messages[indexPath.row] != ""
   ```
2. Reset the state of your cell when it is reused, this provides deterministic behaviour in the table view controller, without burdening the controller class with tasks that a cell should do. This can be done by overwriting `prepareForReuse` in `CathyTaskLogTableViewCell`.

   ```
   func prepareForReuse() {
       super.prepareForReuse()
       self.messageButton.hidden = true // or false, depending on what's the initial state
       // other stuff that needs reset
   }
   ```

With the current code, `messageButton` gets hidden only if the cell doesn't find something in `messages`. So for cells that had this button visible, were reused, and now correspond to a cell that doesn't have a correspondent in `messages`, the button will remain visible.